# How to enable whitespace insensitive mode of regular expression in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I've tried "m" modifier,but not working:

```
$reg = '/...
        /m';

preg_match($reg,...,$match);
```

**EDIT**

Or maybe I need a modifier that can ignore white space like ENTER,TAB and so on.
Because when I remove the white space in my regex it works.

**EDIT AGAIN**:

I need a modifier so that regular expression

```
"/aaaa b/",
"/aaaa
 b/"
```

are the same thing,say,it just ignores the white space in regex itself.

Comment: could you elaborate your situation with more context details?

Comment: yes knowing what your regular expression is would helps, also . doesn't match new line by default, if you need . to match really anything use the s modifier ...

Comment: Other parts are all OK,but I need the regex parser to ignore white space in regex,how to?

Comment: @ too much php ,no,'m' doesn't mean whitespace insensitive.

Comment: @Shore: Sorry, I was wrong about the 'm', you need 'x'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The modifier you need is [`x`](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

```
print_r(preg_match('/aaa
        bbb/x', 'aaabbb'));
```

Comment: Finally one understands me!Cheers!Clever guy!

Answer (score 0):

You have probably a problem with dots not matching new lines in your regular expression. You can use the [s](http://php.belnet.be/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) modifier it will make dots match everything even new line.

Hope this helps

it would give

```
/aaaaaaa.+b/ms
```

Also would be a better practice to use \n because depending of your editor (Unix or windows) the newline could be different characters, CR + LF or only LF ... so your code won't be portable.

or to really ignore whitespace in the reg ex

```
function formatRegEx($reg){
 return preg_replace('/(\s+)/m', '\s+', $reg);
}
```

Comment: I need to use RETURN in regex because it's very long.Otherwise it'll be hard to see what on earth it's doing.Anyway,by somehow,there is such a requirement.But how to enable this mode?